# Standard deviation higher than min(X)?

Tags: standard-deviation

Assume we have a roulette (single-zero wheel) and we want to figure the standard deviation for the first dozen numbers {1, 2, 3, ..., 12}. That gives us $\dfrac{12}{37}$ success probability and $\dfrac{25}{37}$ failure probability. Betting \$1 has two outcomes: winning means getting back \$3 (a profit of \$2) or losing means getting nothing back (a loss of \$1)

- $E(X) = 2 \cdot \dfrac{12}{37} + (-1) \cdot \dfrac{25}{37} \approx -0.027$
- $\text{var}(X) = 2^2 \cdot \dfrac{12}{37} + (-1)^2 \cdot \dfrac{25}{37} - 0.027^2 \approx 1.972$
- $\text{sd}(X) \approx \sqrt{1.972} \approx 1.40$

I have two questions regarding this

1. How is it possible for the s.d. to be higher than what we can potentially lose? I would expect it to be less than $1 - 0.027$ (I think). Basically so the value can't dip below our minimum value from the mean.
2. What does the s.d. tell me for this particular example? I understand it in terms of height of a population, that 68% is within one s.d. of the mean. Here the meaning of s.d. is lost on me. Can I use the s.d. here to tell me something what happens if I play 100 times or if 100 people play one game each?

Comment: Think of what happens to your _net wealth_. After each trial, it _increases_ by 1 with probability $\frac{12}{37}$ and decreases by 1 with probability $\frac{25}{37}$. Don't be fooled by thinking that you win 2 with probability $\frac{12}{37}$. Part of that 2 is the fee for playing the game that is being returned to you.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't increase by 2: for \$1 there are two outcomes: I either lose and gain nothing (down \$1 from before) or I win and gain \$3 (up \$2 from before) since I am taking ~$\dfrac{1}{3}$ risk of winning, ~$\dfrac{2}{3}$ risk of losing. I would agree with an increase of 1 if the probability was $\dfrac{18}{37}$ (~ $\dfrac{1}{2}$) instead.

Comment: I will reword the intro paragraph, I may perhaps have wordly it badly.